# Question concerning playing/pausing audio and loading full file rather than buffering?

Tags: javascript, audio

I'm using a local server only (no network at all) and would like to load the full audio file as soon as a possible. The `preload` attribute seems to be completely ignored; so, I tried an object URL. That seems to work in regards to loading the file because I verified that the full file had loaded using `audio.buffered.start(0)` and `audio.buffered.end(0)` which are `0` and the `audio.duration`, respectively.

There are two issues that I do not understand concerning the JavaScript code below.

1. If I pause the audio in a Chrome-based browser, it seems that I can wait any length of time and, when I click play, the audio immediately starts playing at the point it was paused. However, in Firefox, if I wait more than a minute or so, when I click play the timer starts running but the sound doesn't start until about five seconds. Why? Is there something wrong in this code or missing? These audio files are lectures and the user will, most likely, pause, take notes, look something up in another source, and then resume. So, losing five seconds at each resume and having to back-up would likely become quite annoying.

EDIT to 1: The delay to play after pause is not always present; for I have left the applicatio open in Firefox, put the machine to hibernate over night, and upon resuming, it plays immediately from where it was paused. Thus, it must not be the code but a different matter during the session.

2. In Firefox, the object URL can be revoked after `oncanplaythrough` and the audio will still play. In a chrome browser, revoking the object URL throws an error right away. The audio will continue to play for a bit as if it buffered a portion of the object URL data only. What is a proper method of handling the timing of revoking the object URL to ensure no memory leaks?

EDIT to 2: If the object url is store related to the audio, perhaps the `emptied` event would work; otherwise, I know when the audio is changed and can do it then.

It appears to work; I write "appears" because need to run it for long periods to see if any memory leaks result; but the `emptied` event is revoking the object url as long as save it, of course. One issue is that could not assign the new objectURL to `player.objectURL` outside of the `canplaythrough` event (probably `canplay` would work also) of the audio source, because the value was updated before the `emptied` event fired resulting in revoking the current object URL instead of the old one. I assigned it after the audio.src was set to the new object url but that still was not enough time, which, as I write this, seems to make sense. Perhaps, even a setTimeout( .., 0) would have worked.

```
element.addEventListener( 'emptied',
     (evt) => {
        if ( player.objectURL ) {
          URL.revokeObjectURL( player.objectURL );
          player.objectURL = null;
          console.log("Revoked audio object URL from the 'emptied' event handler.");
        }
     },
     useCapture
);

// Once set player.objectURL in the canplaythrough handler,
// evt.target.src !== player.objectURL at the time the
// emptied event fires.
```

Thank you for considering my questions.

```
  fetch( "http://127.0.0.11:8000/audio/68004.mp3", iObj )
  .then( response => {
      console.log("Got a response.");
      if ( !response.ok ) {
        console.log( 'Network response was not ok.' );
      } else {
        const contentType = response.headers.get('content-type');
        if (!contentType || !contentType.includes('audio/mpeg')) {
          throw new TypeError("Oops, we haven't got an audio file!");
        }
      }
      return response.blob();
    })
  .then( result => {
    let objectURL = URL.createObjectURL( result ),
        a = main.audio;
    a.oncanplaythrough = () => {
       a.oncanplaythrough = null;
       a.play()
       .then( result => {
         console.log( result );
         console.log( "Should be playing" );
         player.classList.add("playing");
         //URL.revokeObjectURL( objectURL );
       })
      .catch( err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    };
    a.src = objectURL;
   })
  .catch( e => {
    console.log( "Error in fetch." );
    console.log( e )
   })
   ;

// In a user-initiated event handler ...
  switch (emap.action) {
    case 'play' :
       audio.play()
       .then( result => {
         console.log( result );
         console.log("Should be playing");
         player.classList.add("playing");
       })
       .catch( err => {
         console.log(err);
       });
       break;
    case 'pause' :
       audio.pause();
       player.classList.remove("playing");
       break;
    default:
       console.log("Error in player play: bad action.");
       return;
  }
```